# Error while generating make latexpdf with sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I am currently using sphinx 1.4.9 for documents creation. While giving make latexpdf, I get the following error.

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/lib/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/plain/misc/pdfcolor.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/lib/texmf/tex/latex/config/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)

****! Package keyval Error: pdfencoding undefined.****

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
```

I have searched for pdfencoding in the sphinx.egg, also it only appears in sphinx.sty. 
but I don't know how to define this pdfencoding. whether to edit conf.py or how to do.

Comment: Same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351851

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperref is outdated. Sphinx 1.4.x series was tested to work with Ubuntu Precise (Debian/TeXLive 2009). I can not try it but here is a hack which may help you out. However, perhaps other parts will fail as your TeX install is really old...

put

```
'passoptionstopackages' : """
\\let\\originalPassOptionsToPackage\\PassOptionsToPackage
\\makeatletter
\\def\\PassOptionsToPackage#1{%
  \\def\\@tempa{#1}\\def\\@tempb{pdfencoding=unicode}%
  \\ifx\\@tempa\\@tempb\\expandafter\\@gobbletwo
  \\else\\expandafter\\originalPassOptionsToPackage\\fi {#1}}
\\makeatother
""",
```

inside the `latex_elements` configuration variable of `conf.py`. Could work ...

Comment: i had tried a lot with passoptionstopackages. but seemed to always get an error with  "Package keyval Error: pdfencoding undefined". or unicode undefined. 
for now downgraded the sphinx version to 1.3.6. since the pdfencoding was brought in 1.4.x. working fine at the moment.

Comment: the above redefines the LaTeX `\PassOptionsToPackage` to intercept that specific occasion when it is used with first argument `pdfencoding=unicode`, which is what Sphinx does since 1.4.2. It would be interesting if you could fin in build repertory the LaTeX `.log` file. The top lines will give you information about what kind of TeX installation you use, and if you search for `hyperref` string you will get its package version number and date. Just curious ...